# Xamarin Android | Layout style

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to create this layout style but still I have no idea how to do it?
is there anybody who can help me ?

[image: layout]

I need main layout and in the layout must be on the left image view for color next will be Title with description for fill parrent and on the right side must be img.

Comment: But at least have you tried something? read this and you can have an idea how to start => https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I designed you left flag, title and description labels plus right image view control. Just create new .axml file and use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:height="30dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flagLayout"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#5416B4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#ffa500" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Final result looks like this:

[image]