# How can i position an icon at the top left of the action bar? (or how to make dissapeard that weard whitespace?)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

It is very simple, i have this code than i obtain from another question and start to analize it in order to learn how to make icons position in the top-left of the ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:height="30dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flagLayout"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#5416B4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#ffa500" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code is an example of another question:

[Xamarin Android | Layout style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466475/xamarin-android-layout-style)

But the thing is, for some reason, it render like this:

[image]

The red circle is something i add, and is the center of the question, why it render that space?, how can i eliminate it?

in other word, **how can i place an icone at the top-left of an actionBar?**

If you make an answer teaching how to change it for a toolbar or something like that and place an icon in the top-left, it would be considered a valid answer aswell.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompact the Toolbar is just a fancy Viewgroup ,you can customize it as much as you want.
Try this :

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This should bring your imageView in center of toolbar.

In javadoc, it says:

One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

It means you cannot do it unless you create a custom toolbar or remove the icon.